# How to make Custom curved layout design and set searchview to middle of both layout

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[image: Desired Image]

I want to make home screen UI like the above image.

Comment: You can check out this tutorial and modify it according to your need. https://iirokrankka.com/2017/09/04/clipping-widgets-with-bezier-curves-in-flutter/

Comment: Yes, but If I want to put a search bar in the middle of two layouts then what should I do?

Comment: Use Stack widget and inside that you can use Positioned Widget to position the search bar...Check this on multiple devices or emulator for both to se if it is placed properly on any resolution...Or Create it as a background and then normal Column widget would work...